# Array not displaying in my tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am passing a mutable array over from another viewcontroller by  saving it in nsuserdefaults. I then retrieve it in the new viewcontroller in which it nslogs just fine. I run into a problem when my code reaches numberofrowsinsections. It seems like my tableview is not recognizing my array object. Thanks for any help as I am new at coding.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RecordView.h"
#import "bookCellTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize arr;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableArray  *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"projects"];
    NSLog(@"arr%@", [arr description]);

    #pragma mark - Table view data source
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    bookCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ToBook"];
    if(cell != nil)
    {


       cell.songTitle.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        testLabel.text = @"Hello";  
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [bookView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue:

You have declared your datasource in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSMutableArray  *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

That's not correct, your datasource should be a property , or a variable on class scope at least.

You should initialize it in `viewDidLoad` but declare it on the class level.

It seems like you have one property called `arr` already, a smart compiler should warn you that is ambiguous.

To fix this just remove  `NSMutableArray  *` part of that line, just  like this:

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You are also misusing `NSUserdefault` it is not meant to pass data between controller, it is more appropriate for storing basic user settings values.

To pass data, simply set values on the `ViewController` properties before presenting it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was not able to get it to work. The only way I have been able to pass my array to the next Viewcontroller is by using a nsuserdefaults or by creating a singleton. When using the singleton I am able to nslog the array which means that the object is being passed but I am getting a "nsdictionary length unrecognized selector error" now.

Comment: Sorry about the last comment but my problem has been solved , thanks! This is a great singleton tutorial http://x-code-tutorials.com/2012/06/04/pass-nsobjects-and-values-between-view-controllers/

Comment: @MichaelBain just show me how you call the viewController, and we sort this out